# Slow order by SQL Server

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database, query-performance

In my application, I have a query which performs a search in "files" table.

The table "files" is partitioned by "f"."created" (see the table definition  and has ~26 million rows for the client 19 ("f"."cid = 19).

The point here is, if I do this query:

```
SELECT "f"."id" AS "FileId"  
, "f"."name" AS "FileName"  
, "f"."year" AS "Fileyear"  
, "f"."cid" AS "clientId"
, "f"."created" AS "FileDate"
, CASE WHEN ("vnVE0"."value" is not null AND "vnVE0"."value" != '')                           
                                THEN CAST("vnVE0"."value" AS decimal(28,2))
                                ELSE 0 END AS "keywordValueCol0_numeric"
FROM files "f"  
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        VT.[value]
    FROM dbo.value_number AS VT
    WHERE
        VT.id_file = F.id
        AND VT.id_field = 260
) AS "vnVE0"
WHERE "grapado" IS NULL AND "masterversion" IS NULL AND ("f"."year" = 2013 OR "f"."year" = 0) AND "f"."cid" = 19
GROUP BY "f"."id", "f"."name", "f"."year", "f"."cid", "f"."created", CASE WHEN ("vnVE0"."value" is not null AND "vnVE0"."value" != '')                           
                            THEN CAST("vnVE0"."value" AS decimal(28,2))
                            ELSE 0 END
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

I get the results in 0 seconds, with the following execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkV0-FDcG

[image: Query without ORDER BY]

But If I try to order by "name" the query becomes too slow:

```
SELECT "f"."id" AS "FileId"  
, "f"."name" AS "FileName"  
, "f"."year" AS "Fileyear"  
, "f"."cid" AS "clientId"
, "f"."created" AS "FileDate"
, CASE WHEN ("vnVE0"."value" is not null AND "vnVE0"."value" != '')                           
                                THEN CAST("vnVE0"."value" AS decimal(28,2))
                                ELSE 0 END AS "keywordValueCol0_numeric"
FROM files "f"  
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        VT.[value]
    FROM dbo.value_number AS VT
    WHERE
        VT.id_file = F.id
        AND VT.id_field = 260
) AS "vnVE0"
WHERE "grapado" IS NULL AND "masterversion" IS NULL AND ("f"."year" = 2013 OR "f"."year" = 0) AND "f"."cid" = 19
GROUP BY "f"."id", "f"."name", "f"."year", "f"."cid", "f"."created", CASE WHEN ("vnVE0"."value" is not null AND "vnVE0"."value" != '')                           
                            THEN CAST("vnVE0"."value" AS decimal(28,2))
                            ELSE 0 END
ORDER BY "f"."name"
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

This query takes 11 minutes to return me the results, with the following execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk3Fbtv9M

[image: Query with ORDER BY]

Also, if I change the order by column, the result is the same.

As you can see in the execution plan, the index "files_mv" has a cost of 61%, this is the index definition:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_mv] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [masterversion] ASC,
    [year] ASC,
    [cat_id] ASC,
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [sub_id] ASC,
    [tip_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

I use SQL Server with Azure. Specifically, Azure SQL Database with pricing/model tier "S4 Estándar (200 DTUs)".

I'm receiving a lot of data but I think the internet connection is not a bottleneck, because in other queries I receive a lot of data too and they're faster.

Also, I'm doing a massive insert of data in this tables, and in a few days I will have up to ~240 million rows in files table (for one cid) and ~480 million rows in value_number table.

**Additional info**

Partiton function "PF_files_partitioning":

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_files_partitioning (DATETIME2(7))
AS
RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ( '2013-03-31 23:59:59', 
                        '2013-06-30 23:59:59',
                        '2013-09-30 23:59:59',
                        '2013-12-31 23:59:59',
                        '2014-03-31 23:59:59', 
                        '2014-06-30 23:59:59',
                        '2014-09-30 23:59:59',
                        '2014-12-31 23:59:59',
                        '2015-03-31 23:59:59', 
                        '2015-06-30 23:59:59',
                        '2015-09-30 23:59:59',
                        '2015-12-31 23:59:59',
                        '2016-03-31 23:59:59', 
                        '2016-06-30 23:59:59',
                        '2016-09-30 23:59:59',
                        '2016-12-31 23:59:59',
                        '2017-03-31 23:59:59', 
                        '2017-06-30 23:59:59',
                        '2017-09-30 23:59:59',
                        '2017-12-31 23:59:59',
                        '2018-03-31 23:59:59')
```

Partition scheme "PS_files_partitioning":

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_files_partitioning AS PARTITION PF_files_partitioning ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
```

** I will have around 15 million rows in each partition.

files table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[files](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cid] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [eid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [cat_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [tip_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [sub_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [caducidad] [smallint] NULL,
    [grapadopri] [int] NOT NULL,
    [grapado] [bigint] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [extension] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [size] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [id_doc] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [observaciones] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [indexed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [signed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [name_lower] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [modified] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [related] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [masterversion] [bigint] NULL,
    [versioned] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [hwsignature] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [blockedUserId] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_files_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC,
    [created] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created]),
 CONSTRAINT [files$estructure_unique] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [cat_id] ASC,
    [tip_id] ASC,
    [sub_id] ASC,
    [year] ASC,
    [name] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [created] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

value_number table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[value_number](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_file] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [id_field] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [value] [nvarchar](255) NULL DEFAULT (NULL),
    [id_doc] [bigint] NULL DEFAULT (NULL)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_value_number_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

*Indexes of files table*

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_clientes] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([id]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_grapado] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [grapado] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_mv] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [masterversion] ASC,
    [year] ASC,
    [cat_id] ASC,
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [sub_id] ASC,
    [tip_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_ocr] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [indexed] ASC,
    [masterversion] ASC,
    [extension] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [eid],
    [cat_id],
    [tip_id],
    [sub_id],
    [year],
    [name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_ocr2] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [indexed] ASC,
    [masterversion] ASC,
    [extension] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [cat_id],
    [tip_id],
    [sub_id],
    [year],
    [name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [files_ocr3] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [cat_id] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [indexed] ASC,
    [masterversion] ASC,
    [extension] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [eid],
    [tip_id],
    [sub_id],
    [year],
    [name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [busqueda_name] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [year] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id],
    [cat_id],
    [tip_id],
    [sub_id],
    [grapadopri],
    [name],
    [size],
    [id_doc],
    [signed],
    [created],
    [modified],
    [related],
    [masterversion]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [busqueda2] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [cat_id] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [masterversion] ASC,
    [year] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [cid] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [eid] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [eid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [extension] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [extension] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FK_files_archivo] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [grapado] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FK_files_tipo] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [tip_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [grapadopri] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [grapadopri] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index_all] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [masterversion] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [cat_id],
    [tip_id],
    [sub_id],
    [year],
    [grapadopri],
    [name],
    [size],
    [id_doc],
    [signed],
    [created],
    [modified],
    [related],
    [versioned]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_7_6] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [name] ASC,
    [year] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ocrCloudClients] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [grapado] ASC,
    [indexed] ASC,
    [extension] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [cid],
    [eid],
    [cat_id],
    [tip_id],
    [sub_id]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [searchEntity] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [cid] ASC,
    [eid] ASC,
    [grapado] ASC,
    [masterversion] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [sub_id] ON [dbo].[files]
(
    [sub_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON PS_files_partitioning([created])
```

*Indexes of value_number table*

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [searchValues] ON [dbo].[value_number]
(
    [id_field] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [id_file],
    [value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [search] ON [dbo].[value_number]
(
    [id_file] ASC,
    [id_field] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [id_field] ON [dbo].[value_number]
(
    [id_field] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FK_valueesN_documento] ON [dbo].[value_number]
(
    [id_doc] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FK_valueesN_archivo] ON [dbo].[value_number]
(
    [id_file] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Statistics are up to date. I have changed the data types for year and other columns and now the performance seems to be a little better, but the execution plan is still the same. I'm trying to fix the Cardinality Estimation (changing index), but I hadn't success yet. According to Azure documentation I should have 130 compatibility level in the database and I already have 100 with ProductVersion 12.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Analysis

For the query with no order preference, SQL Server can stream grouped rows using a Hash Match Flow Distinct. If it encounters the required number of distinct entries quickly, the execution time is short.

When a specific order is required, SQL Server must test every row. For example, to place rows in `name` order, it must sort all rows by name. This will be slow if there are a lot of rows, and no index to provide that order without sorting.

There are a number of fundamental complications in your case, most notably the partitioning, and the disjunction on `[year]`. The partitioning means your indexes cannot deliver the order you might expect. For example an index on `name` is actually sorted first by partition number, then by name. It cannot deliver rows sorted on `name` alone.

You also have `FORCED PARAMETERIZATION` set. This may be beneficial overall, but it comes with impacts you should fully understand. That combined with the partitioning and multi-column indexes means your statistics are largely useless.

The disjunction on `year` also messes with ordering, and means SQL Server can only seek `year >= 0 and year <= 2013` in your plan. This is much less selective than seeking on `year = 0` and `year = 2013` separately.

#### Recommendations

So, in light of all the above:

A good index for the `ORDER BY name` query is:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX dbo.files cid, year, name : grapado IS NULL AND masterversion IS NULL] 
ON dbo.files (cid, [year], [name])
INCLUDE (grapado, masterversion)
WHERE grapado IS NULL AND masterversion IS NULL;
```

A better index for the `value_number` table is:

```
CREATE INDEX [IX dbo.value_number id_file, id_field, value] 
ON dbo.value_number (id_file, id_field, [value]);
```

The query can then be written to fetch at most 50 rows for each year and partition. We then take the first 50 in order from the combined set:

```
WITH PartitionNumbers AS
(
    -- Each partition of the table
    SELECT P.partition_number
    FROM sys.partitions AS P
    WHERE P.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.files', N'U')
    AND P.index_id = 1
)
SELECT
    FF.id,
    FF.[name],
    FF.[year],
    FF.cid,
    FF.created,
    vnVE0.keywordValueCol0_numeric
FROM PartitionNumbers AS PN
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        F100.*
    FROM 
    (
        -- 50 rows in order for year 2013
        SELECT
            F.id,
            F.[name],
            F.[year],
            F.cid,
            F.created
        FROM dbo.files AS F
        WHERE
            F.grapado IS NULL
            AND F.masterversion IS NULL
            AND F.[year] = 2013
            AND F.cid = 19
            AND $PARTITION.PF_files_partitioning(F.created) = PN.partition_number
        ORDER BY
            F.[name]
            OFFSET 0 ROWS
            FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY

        UNION ALL

        -- 50 rows in order for year 0
        SELECT
            F.id,
            F.[name],
            F.[year],
            F.cid,
            F.created
        FROM dbo.files AS F
        WHERE
            F.grapado IS NULL
            AND F.masterversion IS NULL
            AND F.[year] = 0
            AND F.cid = 19
            AND $PARTITION.PF_files_partitioning(F.created) = PN.partition_number
        ORDER BY
            F.[name]
            OFFSET 0 ROWS
            FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS F100
) AS FF
OUTER APPLY
(
    -- Lookup distinct values
    SELECT
        keywordValueCol0_numeric = 
            CASE
                WHEN VN.[value] IS NOT NULL AND VN.[value] <> ''
                THEN CONVERT(decimal(28, 2), VN.[value])
                ELSE CONVERT(decimal(28, 2), 0)
            END
    FROM dbo.value_number AS VN
    WHERE
        VN.id_file = FF.id
        AND VN.id_field = 260
    GROUP BY
        VN.[value]
) AS vnVE0
ORDER BY
    FF.[name]
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

The execution plan will sort at most 100 rows from the `files` table:

[image: estimated plan]

A different index would generally be required for each different ordering.

If you need to count the total number of results, use:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
FROM dbo.files AS F
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT VN.[value]
    FROM dbo.value_number AS VN
    WHERE
        VN.id_file = F.id
        AND VN.id_field = 260
) AS vnVE0
WHERE
    F.grapado IS NULL
    AND F.masterversion IS NULL
    AND F.[year] IN (0, 2013)
    AND F.cid = 19;
```

[db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdc5ae410eabe92c6eaf1d705f1f466c)